# Surface charge density on an open conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, boundary-conditions

In Griffiths' "Introduction to electrodynamics" (3rd edition, page 102) he states that:

**since the electric field inside a conductor is zero**, boudary condition 2.33 ($\mathbf{E_{above}-E_{below}}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\mathbf{\hat{n}}$) ...yields (Eq. 2.49) $\sigma=-\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}$.

This is all nice and well, and was also explained thoroughly in [Obtaining Surface Charge Density from the Potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391892/obtaining-surface-charge-density-from-the-potential?rq=1).

But then, in problem 13.3 (problem 13.4 in 4th edition), Eq. 2.49 is applied for a case in which the electric field on the other side is **not** zero:

The problem is based on Example 3.3, where two infinite grounded metal plates lie parallel to the $xz$ plane, one at $y = 0$, the other at $y = a$ (see figure below). The left end, at $x = 0$, is closed off with an infinite strip insulated from the two plates and maintained at a specific potential $V_o(y)$. The potenetial **inside** the slot is calculated in the example. Then, in problem 13.3 we are asked to "determine the charge density $\sigma(y)$ on the strip at $x = 0$, assuming it is a conductor at constant potential $V_o$". The solution (as appearing in Griffiths' instructor's solutions manual) is simply to apply Eq. 2.49 to the inside potential calculated in Example 3.3.

How is that correct? In this problem, the electric field in the other side of the strip ($x < 0$) is **not** zero, and so Eq. 2.49 is not applicable. In fact, what should have been used here is the complete form of the boundary condition 2.33, but since we haven't calculated the potential (or the field) outside the system we don't have s traightforward way to apply it and calculate the surface charge density.

What am I missing here?

[image]